# How to export variables in Jenkins workspace?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to automate Jenkins installation, passing username and password in a Groovy script that start with jenkins server, but I noticed that the variables exported in bash, /etc/profile or /etc/environment are not visible in the script. If I use:

```
def env = System.getenv()
env each {
  println
}
```

I see many variables, but none that I declared. Someone can point me in the right direction here?

Thank you all!!

Comment: It depends on how you are staring Jenkins, Linux version, and where are your env vars defined

Comment: @daggett I'm using jenkins on linux and I need to to use variables in the the flie that start with jenkins, files in the folder "init.groovy.d".